# Debug a js file in Chrome DevTools if any line of it is executed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to debug input events in my code.

I'm interested in one file full of fuctions declarations. I know that if I put one debug point in every first single line of all the functions I can know if one of them is executed.

Is there another way to do that? I mean I need the debug mode starts if any line of this .js file is executed.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

### Debugger Statement

You can use the [debugger](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_debugger.asp); statement. You leave it in the code, and it will cause the debugger to execute.

What I would do would be to create a custom function e.g. `debugMe();` where inside you would call `console.log` and also `debugger;`

Comment: It only works when the devtools/console is already opened though `Note: If no debugging is available, the debugger statement has no effect`

Comment: But what I want to get is like put breakpoints in every single line of the file. Because i want to know if any function or line of the script is beeing used.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way. You can add `debugger` statement at the start of each function. Read more about it over [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger).